# Moving x rows up in a dataframe indexed on dates

Tags: python, dataframe, rows

I have a dataframe that has **Date as its index**. The dataframe has stock market related data so the dates are not continuous. If I want to move lets say 120 rows up in the dataframe, how do I do that. For example:

If I want to get the data starting from 120 trading days before the start of yr 2018, how do I do that below:

```
df['2018-01-01':'2019-12-31']
```

Thanks

Comment: Consider selecting correct answer for the question. Don't keep unsolved miseries this will not help other developers who are seeking for the same solution identify the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using pandas and the dataframe is sorted by dates, a very simple way would be:

```
initial_date = '2018-01-01'

initial_date_index = df.loc[df['dates']==initial_date].index[0]

offset=120

start_index = initial_date_index-offset


new_df = df.loc[start_index:]
```

Comment: Thanks much. Another follow up - if I don't know whats the first date in 2018 (eg if the markets were closed on Jan 1, it could be 2018-01-02), then how do I go 120 rows back from that first row of year 2018?

Comment: Because the rows are sorted by dates, just grab the first row in 2018, i.e set initial_date = df[df['dates'].str.contains("2018")].index[0] . Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
df[df.columns[df.columns.get_loc('2018-01-01'):df.columns.get_loc('2019-12-31')]]
```

Get location of both Columns in the column array and index them to get the desired.

**UPDATE :**

Based on your requirement, make some little modifications of above.

**Yearly Indexing**

```py
>>> df[df.columns[(df.columns.get_loc('2018')).start:(df.columns.get_loc('2019')).stop]]
```

Above `df.columns.get_loc('2018')` will give out numpy slice object and will give us index of first element of 2018 (which we index using `.start` attribute of slice) and similarly we do for index of last element of 2019.

**Monthly Indexing**

Now consider you want data for First 6 months of 2018 (without knowing what is the first day), the same can be done using:

```py
>>> df[df.columns[(df.columns.get_loc('2018-01')).start:(df.columns.get_loc('2018-06')).stop]]
```

As you can see above we have indexed the first 6 months of 2018 using the same logic.

Comment: Thank you. The next issue I am running into is that I don't know the actual dates for 2018 beginning and 2019 end. The first date in 2018 could be Jan 2 and the last date in 2019 could be Dec 30. How do I generalize the above to start from 120 rows before the first row of 2018 and go till last row of 2019?